# Media library vs entity browser

Tags: media

I am creating a brand new multilingual drupal 10 site and I have to choose between Media library and Entity browser for the manage form display of my media reference fields. I have searched all over the web but I can't find a clear comparison between the two. From what I noticed from testing, media library has a better UX/UI comparing to entity browser. However, it doesn't add an "edit" button for the media on the node edit page. So if I want to change the alt or the title or modify any extra field that I've added to my media, I can't do this from the article node edit page,  I have to go to /media/mediaID/edit. I think It is not that bad it the website doesn't change a lot. But in my case the website is multilingual, so the user will have to changge the alt and the title at least once ( when he creates the article's english version) so I guess it is not practical for me to use media library, it is better to use entity browser that provides the edit button but still I have to apply this patch https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser/issues/2721665 .
On the other hand, when we have a field that can reference to media of type video Or media of type image (both of them), the media library provides better UX to select a video or image, but I know this is possible too in Entity browser if I add new widget for ImageAndVideo.
Could someone help me confirm entity browser is the most convenient in my case ? Or give me some more scenarios to test ?

Comment: You can have edit button on core media with this module. https://www.drupal.org/project/media_library_edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both do essentially the same thing, but media library only allows for the selection of Media entities, whereas Entity Browser can allow for the selection of any type of entity.

Media library is easier to set up and works better out of the box. Entity browsers take a bit of work to learn exactly how to set them up, with a lot of trial and error and sometimes confusing failures.

I personally use Entity Browser, even with its difficulties, as it provides a consistent interface between entity types, rather than having one browser for Media entities and another for other entities. That said, if a site only needed a browser for Media and not other entity types, I'd probably only use the Media library.

Comment: Note that although I've responded, it's likely this question will get closed down, as it's the question requires an opinion-based response, and such questions aren't allowed on Stack Overflow which requires a direct QA format. Open ended discussions like this one go much further in the Drupal forums.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! I will use entity browser with inline entity form  because it is easier to translate alt and title for multilingual sites without the need to use media library edit module